# what does" readin" predicate in prolog mean?

Tags: prolog

I have a question and I hope to help me:

what does" readin" predicate in prolog do?

I have searched in google but I have nothing

could you explain it to me with an example?

Regards.

Comment: what implementation of prolog are you using? I cannot find anything either. are you sure that it's a build-in predicate and not something defined in the code? do you have any code that uses it?

Comment: thank you for answer but I have nothing about it also I have not code.I use SWI. yes I am sure it is built-in predicate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must be seeing `readln` not `readin`.  The library predicate `readln/1` reads tokens from an input line in the interactive SWI-Prolog console and makes a list of them.  Most Prolog term reading predicates require a period to terminate input, but this predicate would include any terminating period in the list.

See [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/readln.pl?show=src) for a bit of documenation.